# Why is single int 24 bytes, but in list it tends to 8 bytes

Tags: python

Here is what I am looking at:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.getsizeof(45)
Out[2]: 24

In [3]: sys.getsizeof([])
Out[3]: 72

In [4]: sys.getsizeof(range(1000))
Out[4]: 8072
```

I know that `int` in Python is growable (can get bigger that 24 bytes) objects that live on the heap, and I see why that object can be quite large, but isn't a list just a collections of such objects? Apparently it is not, what is going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the size of the object - [excluding the objects it contains](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

```
>>> d = range(10)
>>> sys.getsizeof(d)
152
>>> d[0] = 'text'
>>> sys.getsizeof(d)
152
>>> d
['text', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The size of the list with 1000 elements, in your case, is `8072` bytes but each integer object is still `24` bytes. The list object keeps track of these integer objects but they're not included in the size of the list object.

Comment: Now, everything makes sense. Thank You. It was a silly oversight by me.

Answer (score 7):

The list doesn't contain any integers; it contains pointers to various objects, which happen to be integers and which are stored elsewhere. `getsizeof()` tells you the size only of the object you pass to it, not of any additional objects it points to.

Answer (score 2):

A `list` is a collection of *pointers* to objects, not of the objects themselves.  So, assuming a 64-bit system, your list has 8000 bytes of pointers plus 72 bytes of overhead.